# Get the id of the row that was clicked on

Tags: apex, visualforce, table, id-comparison

I've made another question since I couldn't find an affordable solution to my other post ([Inline ajax edit of pageBlockTable columns](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17475/inline-ajax-edit-of-pageblocktable-columns)).

So what I'm looking now, and it's my only problem, is how I can find the ID of the row that I clicked on a table/list. I've made two buttons (Edit and Delete) on the left side of each row. It always opens a popup for creating a new record, but now I need to populate the fields from when I press "Edit", as well as finding which record to update and delete.

Some code (it already lists):

Edit
                 | 
                Del

The {!URLFOR($Action.SomeObject__c.Delete, item.id)}" is to be replaced by the call of the popup, it just like this while I can't find a solution.

Best Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a javascript function the Id of the record you are working with and then open a VF page with the Id as a URL parameter.

This is assuming you are using a PageBlockTable to iterate over your records and you have a command button in a column in that table.  I took some code that I have used in the past as an example

```
<apex:column headerValue="Edit">
     <apex:commandButton onclick="myFunction('{!var.Id}');return false;" value="Open Popup"/>
</apex:column>

<script>
function myFunction(myId) {
    var url = '/apex/myVFPage?theId=' + myId;
        newWin = window.open(url, '', toolbar=0, location=0, status=0, menubar=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, width=700, height=400, left=200, top=200');

    if (window.focus) {
        newWin.focus();
    }    
    return false;
}
</script>
```

> EDIT

If you want to just pass the Id to the controller you can make the button call an action function and pass the Id as a param

```
<apex:column headerValue="Edit">
     <apex:commandButton onclick="myFunction('{!var.Id}');" value="Open Popup"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:actionfunction name="myActionFunction" action="{!myControllerMethod}">
     <apex:param name="recordId" value=""/>
</apex:actionfunction>

<script>
function myFunction(myId) {
    myActionFunction(myId);
}
</script>
```

> EDIT

**In the Controller**

```
public myControllerMethod(){
     Id myId = system.currentPageReference.getParameters.get('recordId');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was the method I was using in the first place, but for a user-friendly oriented method I want to use that "new page" as a popup modal dialog form, which is already being used but only to insert data at the moment, where I can create a new object without needing any ID. 
The thing I'm missing is getting that ID into my controller to edit the chosen row.

Comment: If you need to pass the Id to the controller, you can use an actionfunction and pass a Apex:param that is the Id of the record

Comment: Added some code to demonstrate

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Sorry for asking, but can you confirm me how will !myControllerMethod fetch the parameter? <apex:param name="recordId" value=""/> will have the dynamic value of myId everytime it is invoked right? Can't test at the moment so I'm asking so I can use it when I'm able to. Thanks you once again!

Comment: No prob, Updated the code to show how to fetch the value on the controller.  Hope that helps

Comment: Very nice, I had used the getParameters reference before but not this way, very cool! Thank you so much.

Comment: Not a problem.  Glad to help